# How do I increase the terminal border size in xfce?

Tags: command-line, xubuntu, xfce, xml, greybird

The terminal (and other applications) borders seem to be only 1 pixel wide which makes them almost impossible to click. I am aware that alt+right click has the same function, but I need the borders able to be clicked. I found this solution:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-2d/+bug/878198/comments/8

but unfortunately it did not work for me (i'm using Greybird as a theme, I tried the same fix with Bluebird and it also didn't work). I am using Xubuntu 12.04 xfce by the way. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Still need help with this issue please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of the other themes provide a border that is easier to grab.  For example, I use Daloa  on one of my Xfce systems.  So unless you really need Greybird for some reason, I recommend trying a few of the window manager themes to find one you like.

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, use `<Alt+Left Click>` to move windows and `<Alt+Right Click>` to resize windows, which doesn't require that you click on the edge at all.